# Incrementing state in a parent from a child component in react

Tags: reactjs, state, parent-child

I have a component that has a counter in state, the child component does some checks and updates the count using an increment function that is passed to the child.
I can see that it is working but it only ever increments to 1, what am I missing here

**Parent Component**

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import Child from './child'
function Parent() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const increment = () => {setCount(count +1)}
  const children = [
    {
      "name": "one",
      "answered": true,
      "id": "001"
    },
    {
      "name": "two",
      "answered": false,
      "id": "002"
    },
    {
      "name": "three",
      "answered": true,
      "id": "003"
    }
  ]
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Parent</h1>
      <progress id="file" max={children.length} value={count}>{count}/{children.length}</progress>
      <ul>
        {children.map((child, index) => {
          return (<Child key={index} increment={increment} child={child}></Child>)
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}
export default Parent
```

**Child Component**:

```
function Child(props) {
  const child = props.child
  if (child.answered) {
    props.increment()
  }
  return (<li>{child.name}</li>)
}
export default Child
```

Comment: This is a classic issue with React. You're using an old instance in your state setter. Use `setState((prevValue) => callback(prevValue))` instead

Answer (score 1):

Firstly thank you @GalAbra

I fixed this by updating the `setCount()` to use a callback function.
React's useState's setter will populate with the current value

```
const increment = () => {setCount(c => c +1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using count and incrementing it every time doesn't seems to be  optimized solution for this use case
try this  replace it with count

```
{children.filter(item => item.answered).length}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. 
I simplifed the problem here, the information is being built dynamically and not just coming from an array.

Comment: Even if it’s dynamic you can attach your api data with this method